# Word document symbol is not visible in site?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, site-collection

In my site, the symbol for word document, pdf, excel is not visible, if i add any document to my site. so, please guide me any proper solution.
[image]

Comment: what shareoint version you are using, online or on prem? did you have access to sharepoint servers?

Comment: I am using SharePoint 2010, i have full access to server and moreover its not access level issue.

Comment: i am not saying it is access issue...but if you have access to sharepoint server, then from 14 hive check if docicon.xml is correct and all images are in the folder. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2646696/en-us

Comment: The image is available in C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\IMAGES. is it right ?

Comment: Thanks Waqas sarwar. i just replace the docicon.xml file from another server to the problem occurred server. now its working fine.

Comment: i added my comment as answer so that you can mark it as answer for benefit of community and me as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their are couple of reasons for the issue.

1. Make sure the imgages are still in the Imgaes folder on 14 hive( all server in farm)
2. Make sure Docicon.xml is correct( sometime its become corrupt or somebody make changes in it which cause broken image).location of file is C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\IMAGES.